# clang tidy complains about push_back into vector in a loop

Tags: c++, vector, push-back

Here's my code(works fine), and the complaint of IDE:
[image]
I tried setting vector size with `vector<string> result(tmp.size());` but after that, result will contain `tmp.size()` amount of empty strings in the front, and I don't wan't to use `insert`.

Is there any better workaround on this?

Comment: This is about optimization. With push back each time you reach the vector allocated size it need to be re-alocated. If you allocate if before and use insert, it will run faster. Or you can use reserve to avoid re-allocation

Comment: I think the `clang-tidy` message is suggesting [`std::vector::reserve`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/reserve) rather than `std::vector::resize`.

Comment: Note that if `decltype(*mph)` supported iterators, then you could simply do `std::vector<std::string> result(mph->begin(), mph->end());`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"*pre-allocate*" here does not mean to *resize* the vector to the final size, which is what `vector<string> result(tmp.size());` does, but to *reserve* memory for the final size:

```
vector<string> result;
result.reserve(tmp.size());
```

As mentioned in the comments that is purely meant as performance optimization. It doesn't change the behavior of the code. The `reserve` call will cause allocation of a memory block large enough to hold the final vector size, but doesn't construct any of the elements yet, which would still be done with `push_back`.

This is a performance optimization because otherwise the final size is not known to the vector and so it may need to reallocate memory blocks multiple times during the loop, which will (asymptotically for large sizes) increase the time that the loop takes by a constant factor, assuming the length of the strings is bounded and the call to `mph->getValue()` is `O(1)`, otherwise the effect will be less significant.